# Windows: setting a program up to run with admin permissions, not using the user interface?

Tags: windows, permissions, administrator

I am working on a forensic riddle game that needs to mount a VHD disk (exact copy of a real USB stick which was the basis of the hardware version) using AttachVirtualDisk(). That requires elevated privileges, otherwise AttachVirtualDisk returns ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD (hardly surprising). I can ask users to right click the exe and choose "Run as admin", I can ask them to set it up to be run as administrator permanently by right clocking and choosing Properties tab, but I don't want to bother them with these actions.

Is there a way to achieve the same effect without asking users to use the user interface? Some API calls that would allow me to set up the program during installation or on a first run so that it is permanently configured to be run as admin? Yes, users will still see the nag screen, I don't want to hide the fact program uses elevated privileges, just to make the process as transparent/easy to the user as possible.

(Actually if there is a way to make the AttachVirtualDisk() work without program being run as admin that would do the trick as well, but I doubt it is possible, wouldn't make sense.)

Comment: you should be able to set the exe to always prompt for admin access, in Properties->Compatibility settings, if thats what you are asking about. I'm not sure how you set that via the installer, but I'm sure there's a way.

Comment: The way I do this is to check if you are running elevated, and if not restart yourself as elevated using the “runas” verb. There is not much detail here to go on. Windows has a mechanism to check for an elevated token and to start a process with an elevated token. This is one mechanism: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch. And https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Please limit your post to a single question.